# Rails Gravatar Helper Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, helper, gravatar

I have gone through this [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/244-gravatar) on Gravatars and i now have the below helper method in my application helper.

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def avatar_url(user)
    gravatar_id = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(user.email.downcase)
    "http://gravatar.com/avatar/#{gravatar_id}.png?s=200"
  end
end
```

and i have this in my view

```
<%= image_tag avatar_url(user) %>
```

how can i modify the helper so it will accept a size option that changes the s=200 to the size specified?

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def avatar_url(user, size)
    gravatar_id = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(user.email.downcase)
    "http://gravatar.com/avatar/#{gravatar_id}.png?s=#{size}"
  end
end
```

Then call:

```
<%= image_tag avatar_url(user, 200) %>
```

You can also check [Michael Hartl's](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-up#sec-a_gravatar_image) guide.

Answer (score 1):

In the `application_helper.rb` file under the `app/helpers` folder, add the following method:

```
# app/helpers/application_helper.rb

def gravatar_for(user, options = { size: 200})
  gravatar_id = Digest::MD5::hexdigest(user.email.downcase)
  size = options[:size]
  gravatar_url = "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/#{gravatar_id}?s=#{size}"
  image_tag(gravatar_url, alt: user.username, class: "img-circle")
end
```

Then call it at the `show.html.erb`:

```
<%= gravatar_for @user, size: 200%>
```